# Getting a value 3 levels down a nested hashmap in scala

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have the following nested Hashmap -

```
  val  P = HashMap("a"->HashMap("aa"->HashMap("aaa"-> 0.25,"aab"-> 0.95),
                                "ab"->HashMap("aba"-> 0.2, "abb"-> 0.8)),
                   "b"->HashMap("ba"->HashMap("baa"-> -0.3,"bab"-> -0.4,"bac"-> -0.2),
                                "bb"->HashMap("bba"-> 0.3, "bbb" -> 0.4, "bbc"-> 0.4)),
                   "c"->HashMap("ca"->HashMap("caa"-> 0.2,"cab" -> 0.001),
                                "cb" -> HashMap()))
```

How do I get to `val m = P("a")("ab")("aba")` ?
It throws the following error -

```
Compilation Failed
Main.scala:59: type mismatch;
 found   : String("aba")
 required: _12 where type _12 <: String
P("a")("ab")("aba") 
             ^
```

`val m = P("a")("ab")` however works, giving `Map("aba" -> 0.2, "abb" -> 0.8)`. How do I get the "aba" key value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could annotate the type properly, and I would also recommend another code formatting if you really initialize something like that statically:

```
val someValue: String = "key" 
val someOtherValue: Double = 0.1 

val P: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Double]]] =
  HashMap("a" -> HashMap(
    "aa" -> HashMap(
      "aaa" -> 0.25,
      "aab" -> 1 // implicitly converted to Double
    ),
    "ab" -> HashMap(
      "aba" -> 0.2,
      "abb" -> 0.8)
    ),
    "b" -> HashMap(
      "ba" -> HashMap(
        "baa" -> -0.3,
        "bab" -> -0.4,
        "bac" -> -0.2
      ),
      "bb" -> HashMap(
        // would not compile, though it would compile in the original example
        // messing up the result type completely and good luck finding this
        // with the original formatting
        /* someOtherValue -> someValue, */
        "bba" -> 0.3,
        "bbb" -> 0.4,
        "bbc" -> 0.4
      )
    ),
    "c" -> HashMap(
      "ca" -> HashMap(
        "caa" -> 0.2,
        "cab" -> 0.001
      ),
      "cb" -> HashMap() // Map[String, Double] inferred
    )
  )


val m = P("a")("aa")("aab") // -> 1.0
val m2 = P("a")("ab")("aba") // -> 0.2
```

Comment: I think it's a bit overkill and does not take advantage of Scala type inference, although it works

Comment: That is only partly true. My solution makes use of scala type inference for that last empty `HashMap`. But it has other benefits, too. The example is a manageable sized hard coded HashMap with nested HashMap. Now, If you imagine an even larger such `Map` initialized that statically and if you then think about having more empty `Maps`on different levels. It also would make use of scala implicit conversions where one would write '1' instead of '1.0'. And if one makes use of formatting, the compiler can give better  error/warning messages. I'll update my answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is actually the type inference of `P`, because one of the `HashMap` has no explicit type. Replace `P` with :

```
val  P = HashMap("a"->HashMap("aa"->HashMap("aaa"-> 0.25,"aab"-> 0.95),
                              "ab"->HashMap("aba"-> 0.2, "abb"-> 0.8)),
                 "b"->HashMap("ba"->HashMap("baa"-> -0.3,"bab"-> -0.4,"bac"-> -0.2),
                              "bb"->HashMap("bba"-> 0.3, "bbb" -> 0.4, "bbc"-> 0.4)),
                 "c"->HashMap("ca"->HashMap("caa"-> 0.2,"cab" -> 0.001),
                              "cb" -> HashMap[String, Double]()))
```